# Pandas split from list and unique rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

All, I have python list which has data as below

```
   a_list = [['W1', 'W0'], ['W1', 'W2'], ['W3', 'W1'], ['W4', 'W6'], ['W5', 'W10'],      ['W6', 'W7'], ['W6', 'W7'],['W6','W7'],['W6','W7']]
```

i would like to convert it into pandas dataframe and i used the below code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = a_list)
print(df)
```

Here is the output that i see

```
    0     1
0   W1    W0
1   W1    W2
2   W3    W1
3   W4    W6
4   W5    W10
5   W6    W7
6   W6    W7
7   W6    W7
8   W6    W7
```

But i would like my output to be as

```
      0     
0   W1,W0
1   W1,W2
2   W3,W1
3   W4,W6
4   W5,W10
5   W6,W7
6   W6,W7
7   W6,W7
8   W6,W7
```

and also i would like to eliminate duplicates such as row #6 by having a counter on the side

```
      0      count
0   W1,W0      1
1   W1,W2      1
2   W3,W1      1
3   W4,W6      1 
4   W5,W10     1
5   W6,W7      4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = (df[0] + ',' + df[1]).drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
0     W1,W0
1     W1,W2
2     W3,W1
3     W4,W6
4    W5,W10
5     W6,W7
dtype: object
```

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by column `new`:

```
df['new'] = (df[0] + ',' + df[1])
df['counter'] = df.groupby('new').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
    0    1     new  counter
0  W1   W0   W1,W0        1
1  W1   W2   W1,W2        1
2  W3   W1   W3,W1        1
3  W4   W6   W4,W6        1
4  W5  W10  W5,W10        1
5  W6   W7   W6,W7        1
6  W6   W7   W6,W7        2
```

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
print (df.groupby((df[0] + ',' + df[1])).size().reset_index(name='count'))
    index  count
0   W1,W0      1
1   W1,W2      1
2   W3,W1      1
3   W4,W6      1
4  W5,W10      1
5   W6,W7      4
```

Comment: thanks that helped out . Any idea on how can i have a counter ? for example the row#5 should have a counter of 2 while all others should have a counter as 1

Comment: do you think row `6` ?

Comment: i meant    5   w6,w7  2

Comment: there can be any number of duplicates and for unique i would see 1 and for duplicates i would need to see 2 or more . i tried to use Counter but that does not come as a dataframe

Comment: Yes, Sure.give me a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129571/discussion-between-rohitr-and-jezrael).

Comment: I have edited my question to show what i need in my output

Comment: Thank you. What is output if add to the end `7  W1   W0`and `W1,W2` ?

Comment: Thanks but , it does not work if there are more than 2 repetitive rows.

Comment: Can you add desired output with this sample? `df = pd.DataFrame([['W1', 'W0'], ['W1', 'W0'], ['W1', 'W2'], ['W3', 'W1'], ['W4', 'W6'], ['W5', 'W10'],['W1', 'W2'], ['W3', 'W1'], ['W4', 'W6'],['W6', 'W7'], ['W6', 'W7']])`. Because I dont understand what you need exactly.

Comment: i have edited my question and have added rows #7 and #8 which are duplicates and i have edited my output that i need at the end

Comment: great , i was just about to comment as i just figured out the same using groupby . Thanks for your help !